How to configure nvim-cmp for autocompletion
I am starting to use Neovim and need some basic functions, like autocompletion. I went with vim-plug plugin manager for neovim and found nvim-cmp as autocompletion.
My problem is that when I copy the nvim-cmp config from https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp it does not work. It says: Error loading lua [string ":lua"].
I thing that maybe I need some lua files in config. Right now I have got just init.vim in .config/nvim/. But I didn't find an explanation of how to set it up. I also don't know what I should put in ['YOUR_LSP_SERVER'] in nvim-cmp config (the one on the github page).
Can somebody explain? Do you adwise me to use different autocompletion plugin like coc?

Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Hwo I do that? And do you think I need some lua files, or just the init.vim file is needed. I am more trying to understand how these things work than fix an error (I am not sure if this error isnt normal because I just didnt do somehintg).

Please, if you want some help with your Neovim config, post extract of your init.lua / nvim-cmp config files.

It seems like you are kinda confused at the moment on lot of stuff.
Autocompletion with nvim-cmp and the related projects can be a bit messy but it is manageable when you take a look at the doc.
Here is what I can advice to first familiarize yourself with the ecosystem:

Use Kickstart to setup your first configuration

Alternative: use a distro such as LazyVim, LunarVim...


Take a look at some articles, videos and stuff - there are a lot of content available that will explain you how to start a nvim config from scratch and to get basic configuration working properly.
Take your time, read the doc, read other people config (look dotfiles on github) and enjoy the journey, it will be a long one !

